# Running bitcoind in a different directory

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I installed bitcoin core in windows 10 using ( Windows Subsystem for Linux ) . I installed ubuntu from the store and I used it to Install bitcoin core. The thing is everything was installed in the main hard disk C and it doesn't have enough space to download blocks. Is there a way to copy it to another partition (D partition because it has enough space) ? or while running bitcoind is there any way to run it with a specified path?

Ps: I hope the question is clear

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the data directory with bitcoin-cli?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/47892/how-to-change-the-data-directory-with-bitcoin-cli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to stop bitcoind with `bitcoin-cli stop`, then move your data directory to a new folder and add the following line to your `bitcoin.conf`:

```
datadir=path/to/new/directory
```

This file should be somewhere in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf` in Windows and `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` in Linux.

As the user AntMor replied, you can also pass this configuration every time you run bitcoind.

Comment: Thank you Pedro! I will try it.. Just when I write datadir=path/to/new/directory instead of directory I shoud give the path to my directory, right? And if I do this whenever I run bitcoind it will be run in the directory I gave right? Thanks a lot

Comment: yes, make sure the directory exists and you will notice new files being created as soon as bitcoind starts running. When you run `df -h` on the command line what do you get?

Comment: when İ run df -h  I get this                                          Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          223G  216G  7.2G  97% /
none            223G  216G  7.2G  97% /dev
none            223G  216G  7.2G  97% /run
none            223G  216G  7.2G  97% /run/lock
none            223G  216G  7.2G  97% /run/shm
none            223G  216G  7.2G  97% /run/user
C:              223G  216G  7.2G  97% /mnt/c
D:              932G  113G  820G  13% /mnt/d

Comment: so for d partition I can use this path /mnt/d ?

Comment: yes, try to move the data folder to somewhere in /mnt/d , run bitcoind as root (sudo bitcoind ...) just in case to make sure you have permissions.

Comment: It worked thank you pedro .. but when ı run bitcoin-cli -testnet getblockchaininfo in another terminal ı got this error [ error: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)]

Comment: to enable testnet you need to add `testnet=1` to `bitcoin.conf` and restart bitcoind. It uses mainnet by default. does it work without the `-testnet` option? Also you can remove any `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` from your configuration if you plan to use it locally as it will authenticate with the cookie

Comment: Also remove `rpcbind` and `rpcallowip` if you have any.

Comment: İ will try it..without -testnet it gave me this erroer 8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (111). And bitcoin-cli was working when i don't specify the directory

Comment: when i removed what you told me ı got this error:  error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/home/saadia/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)

Comment: I am guessing it's an issue with permissions, do you see anything being filed in your /mnt/d/... folder? try running `sudo bitcoin-cli ...` and what does your `/mnt/d/.../debug.log` say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102377/discussion-between-pedro-and-saadia).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `bitcoind` with a different `-datadir` parameter. This is, all the blockchain data is under a folder (binaries and database files from LevelDB). What you need to do is something like the following:

```
/path-to-bitcoin/bitcoind -datadir=/path-to-directory/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I find the path of D partition because ubuntu that I have used allows me  to use just the terminal so I can just type commands. How D partition is known inside ubuntu?